# <C-v> <C-i> not working to print literal tab!

Tags: insert-mode, tab-characters

I'm trying to set a custom `breakat` for plain text files. Aiming for a very small set of characters -- just hyphens, slashes, and whitespace. That means I need to add tabs, which I do by setting `breakat+=^I`. (Right?)

At first, I didn't understand how control characters worked, and appended `^` `I` to my `breakat` value. Naturally, as a result, my files started breaking at capital I's. -_-'

So then I went digging, and found [this](http://dailyvim.blogspot.tw/2009/10/ctrl-v-for-literal-characters.html): `<C-v>` followed by any control key should produce the literal control character. Great! Except it seems to work on all the control characters I've tried *except* `<C-i>` (which prints a regular tab, rather than `^I` with the special/bolded syntax highlighting I see for other literal control characters). What gives?

(I thought maybe it was because various plugins map `<C-i>` to lots of things, so I moved my "bundle" folder elsewhere, reloaded vim, and tried again! Still no luck.)

If it helps/matters, I'm running gVim 7.4 on Windows. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4781099/4865822), but `<C-q><C-i>` doesn't do it, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
let &breakat = "-/ \t"
```

`set` syntax is weird, you probably want to avoid it if possible.  Fortunately `set option=...` is equivalent to `let &option = ...`, and `let` syntax is nicer.  In particular `let` allows you to use full expressions as values, such as the above.

On a related topic, `setlocal option=...` is equivalent to `let &l:option = ...`.

Comment: Brilliant; that totally did it! Do you do this for all settings in your `.vimrc`?

Comment: @RyanLue This trick is mostly useful for string-valued options, or when saving / restoring options in scripts.  I don't bother with it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm running gVim 7.4 on Windows.

From [`:help i_CTRL-V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V):

> Note: When `CTRL-V` is mapped (e.g., to paste text) you can often use `CTRL-Q` instead `i_CTRL-Q`.

[`mswin.vim`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui_w32.txt.html#mswin.vim) maps `<C-v>` to paste text.

That being said, using `\t` as suggested by lcd047 is probably better here, since it's more readable and easier to edit.